# Android app running in background must run in foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to receive a notification/event through FIREBASE in Android app that is running in background. After that I need this app runs in foreground. In addition, i need this notification/event to be able to send information in XML or JSON format. Would someone help me?

I tried FCM push Notifications and FCM In-App Messaging Tutorials, but did not find the scenario I need.

Comment: For making the app foreground you must start a foreground service with a notification in your "onMessagesReceived" method. In the same method you can also send JSON data through Http request using external libraries like Volley, OkHttp, Retrofit.